# Get response body using nsiHttpChannel

Tags: javascript, mozilla, gecko

I'm currently creating a Firefox extension application to capture HTTP response and compare its response body (HTML, etc) with data. I am using observer service to capture all HTTP request and response, and implement function observe, register/unregister observer, etc.

Using the function above i can get the request and response header, but i cannot get response body like HTML or other things. Is there any way to get the body using the function i mentioned above?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To view the response body, you'll need to register for the `http-on-examine-response` event, and then `QueryInterface` the subject to `nsITraceableChannel`, as opposed to `nsIHttpChannel`.

The reason for this is that when you receive the HTTP response headers, the response body may not have started to download yet, so the data isn't actually available at that time.

This link should help you:
http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/